# Reference error: weakly-referenced object no longer exists

Tags: android, python, sqlite3, kivy

Сделал приложение на python 3.6 с помощью kivy. В PyCharm и в линуксе запускается и работает. На андройде при нажатии кнопки добавить запись в БД, закрывается и в логе ошибка Reference error: weakly-referenced object no longer exists, но при этом запись добавляется в базу данных.

Функции которые запускаются при нажатии кнопки:

```
    def add_task(self, task_text):
        self.app = App.get_running_app()

        if(len(task_text) > 0):
            if(len(task_text) < 56):
                try:
                    self.app.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO tasks VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?)", (task_text, self.manager.current, self.app.username))
                except sqlite3.DatabaseError as error:
                    self.app.on_error("Ошибка: " + error, self.manager.current)
                else:
                    self.app.conn.commit()
            else:
                self.app.on_error("Ошибка: Текст заметки не может быть длиннее 55 символов", self.manager.current)
        else:
            self.app.on_error("Ошибка: Текст заметки не задан", self.manager.current)
```

```
    def get_tasks_from_db(self):
        self.app = App.get_running_app()
        self.ids.task.clear_widgets()
        self.app.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE task_screen=? AND user_login =? ORDER BY id DESC", (self.manager.current, self.app.username))
        self.rows = self.app.cursor.fetchall()
        for i in self.rows:
            self.app.TaskText = str(i[1])
            self.ids.task.add_widget(TaskLabel(id = str(i[0])))
```

Код обьекта TaskLabel:

```
class TaskLabel(BoxLayout):
    def remove_task(self, id):
        self.app = App.get_running_app()
        #self.conn = sqlite3.connect('users.db')
        #self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
        try:
            self.app.cursor.execute("DELETE FROM tasks WHERE id=?", (id,))
        except sqlite3.DatabaseError as error:
                #print("Ошибка: ", error)
                self.app.on_error("Ошибка: " + error, self.manager.current)
        else:
            self.app.conn.commit()
            #self.conn.close()
```

kv файл:

```
<TaskLabel>:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: 50
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0, 0, 0, 1
        Line:
            width: 1
            rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    Label:
        id: root.id + "_label"
        text_size: (self.width-20, self.height)
        halign: 'left'
        valign: 'middle'
        text: str(app.TaskText)
        font_size: 24
        color: 0, 0, 0, 1
    Button:
        text: "X"
        font_size: 24
        color: 0, 0, 0, 1
        size_hint: (.1, 1)
        background_color: 1, 1, 1, 0
        on_press: root.remove_task(root.id); root.parent.remove_widget(root)
```

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, SlideTransition
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout



import sqlite3 #База данных
import hashlib #Хеширование пароля

from connected import Connected
from register import Register

class Login(Screen):
    def do_login(self, loginText, passwordText):
        self.app = App.get_running_app()
        self.app.username = loginText
        self.app.password = passwordText

        #conn = sqlite3.connect("users.db")
        #cursor = conn.cursor()
        self.cursor_row = self.app.conn.cursor()

        self.app.cursor.execute("SELECT password FROM users WHERE login=?", (loginText,))
        self.rows = self.cursor_row.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE login=?", (loginText,)).fetchone()[0]

        if(self.rows > 0):
            self.hashed_password = "".join(self.app.cursor.fetchone())
            self.pass_without_salt, self.salt = self.hashed_password.split(':')
            self.salt = "".join(self.salt)
            self.pass_without_salt = "".join(self.pass_without_salt)

            def hash_password(password, salt):
                return hashlib.sha256(salt.encode() + password.encode()).hexdigest()

            def checkPassword(password):
                if hash_password(password, self.salt) == self.pass_without_salt:
                    return True


            if((self.rows > 0) and checkPassword(passwordText)):
                self.app.on_change_screen(self.manager.current, 'connected', 'left')
            else:
                self.app.on_error("Ошибка: Неверный логин или пароль", self.manager.current)

    def resetForm(self):
        self.ids['login'].text = ""
        self.ids['password'].text = ""

    def do_register(self):
        self.app = App.get_running_app()
        self.app.on_change_screen(self.manager.current, 'register', 'left')


class ErrorMessageWidget(AnchorLayout):
    pass
#class VoiceMessage(AnchorLayout):
#    pass

class LoginApp(App):
    username = StringProperty(None)
    password = StringProperty(None)
    #ErrorMessage = u""
    #VoiceMessageText = u""

    def on_change_screen(self, screen, target_screen, transition):
        self.root.transition = SlideTransition(direction=transition)
        self.root.current = target_screen
        for child in self.root.get_screen(screen).children[:]:
            if child.id == 'error':
                self.root.get_screen(screen).remove_widget(child)

    def on_error(self, error, screen):
        self.ErrorMessage = error
        self.root.get_screen(screen).add_widget(ErrorMessageWidget(id='error'))

    #def on_message(self, message, screen):
    #    self.VoiceMessageText = message
    #    self.root.get_screen(screen).add_widget(VoiceMessage())


    def build(self):
        manager = ScreenManager()

        self.conn = sqlite3.connect('users.db')
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

        manager.add_widget(Login(name='login'))
        manager.add_widget(Connected(name='connected'))
        manager.add_widget(Register(name='register'))

        return manager

if __name__ == '__main__':
    LoginApp().run()
```

login.kv:

```
#:include connected.kv
#:include register.kv

<Login>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: (1, 1, 1, .7)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    BoxLayout
        id: login_layout
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: [10,50,10,50]
        spacing: 30
        Label:
            text: u'\u0410\u0432\u0442\u043E\u0440\u0438\u0437\u0430\u0446\u0438\u044F'
            #Авторизация
            font_size: 32
            color: 0, 0, 0, 1
            size_hint_y: .1
        AnchorLayout:
            size_hint_y: .8
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                size_hint_y: None
                spacing: 10
                TextInput:
                    id: login
                    multiline:False
                    font_size: 20
                    hint_text: '\u041B\u043E\u0433\u0438\u043D'
                    size_hint_y: None
                    size_hint_x: .5
                    pos_hint: {'x': .25}
                    height: 40
                    padding: [5, 8]

                TextInput:
                    id: password
                    multiline:False
                    password:True
                    hint_text: '\u041F\u0430\u0440\u043E\u043B\u044C'
                    font_size: 20
                    size_hint_y: None
                    size_hint_x: .5
                    pos_hint: {'x': .25}
                    height: 40

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            spacing: 10
            size_hint_y: .1
            Button:
                text: '\u0412\u043E\u0439\u0442\u0438'
                #Войти
                font_size: 24
                color: 0, 0, 0, 1
                background_color: 1, 1, 1, .5
                on_press: root.do_login(login.text, password.text)
            Button:
                text: '\u0420\u0435\u0433\u0438\u0441\u0442\u0440\u0430\u0446\u0438\u044F'
                #Регистрация
                font_size: 24
                color: 0, 0, 0, 1
                background_color: 1, 1, 1, .5
                on_press: root.do_register()
<ErrorMessageWidget>:
    anchor_x: "center"
    anchor_y: "top"
    Button:
        text: app.ErrorMessage
        background_color: 1, 0, 0, 1
        size_hint_y: .05
        on_press: root.parent.remove_widget(root)
#<VoiceMessage>:
#    anchor_x: "center"
#    anchor_y: "top"
#    Button:
#        text: app.VoiceMessageText
#        background_color: 1, 0, 0, 1
#        size_hint_y: .05
#        on_press: root.parent.remove_widget(root)
```

```
<Connected>:
    on_enter: root.get_tasks_from_db()
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: (1, 1, 1, .7)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        spacing: 20
        padding: [10,50,10,50]
        Label:
            text: u"\u0412\u0432\u0435\u0434\u0438\u0442\u0435\u0020\u0442\u0435\u043A\u0441\u0442\u0020\u0437\u0430\u043C\u0435\u0442\u043A\u0438"
            #Введите текст заметки
            font_size: 24
            color: 0, 0, 0, 1
            size_hint_y: .1
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5}
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            size_hint_y: .2
            TextInput:
                id: task_input
                multiline:True
                font_size: 20
                padding: [5, 0]
            Button:
                text: 'Voice'
                on_press: root.get_voice_text()
                size_hint_x: .1
                color: 0, 0, 0, 1
                background_color: 1, 1, 1, .5
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            size_hint_y: .1
            spacing: 20
            Button:
                text: u"\u0414\u043E\u0431\u0430\u0432\u0438\u0442\u044C\u0020\u0437\u0430\u043C\u0435\u0442\u043A\u0443"
                #Добавить заметку
                font_size: 24
                color: 0, 0, 0, 1
                background_color: 1, 1, 1, .5
                on_press: root.add_task(task_input.text); task_input.text = ""; root.get_tasks_from_db()
            Button:
                text: u"\u0421\u043C\u0435\u043D\u0438\u0442\u044C\u0020\u0430\u043A\u043A\u0430\u0443\u043D\u0442"
                #Сменить аккаунт
                font_size: 24
                color: 0, 0, 0, 1
                background_color: 1, 1, 1, .5
                on_press: root.disconnect()
        ScrollView:
            bar_width: 4
            scroll_type: ['bars']
            bar_inactive_color: 5, 20, 10, .5
            bar_color: 5, 10, 15, .8
            size_hint_y: .5
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                id: task
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height

<TaskLabel>:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: 50
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0, 0, 0, 1
        Line:
            width: 1
            rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    Label:
        id: root.id + "_label"
        text_size: (self.width-20, self.height)
        halign: 'left'
        valign: 'middle'
        text: str(app.TaskText)
        font_size: 24
        color: 0, 0, 0, 1
        #on_press: self.text = "[s]" + self.text + "[/s]"
    Button:
        text: "X"
        font_size: 24
        color: 0, 0, 0, 1
        size_hint: (.1, 1)
        background_color: 1, 1, 1, 0
        on_press: root.remove_task(root.id); root.parent.remove_widget(root)
```

Comment: А на какой строчке падает?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб При вызове функции get_tasks_from_db

Comment: Пробовал убрать вызов этой функции с кнопки. Запись добавилась, приложение не вылетело. Но когда запустил функцию эту, сразу опять вылет

Comment: Судя по ошибке у вас GC какой-то объект в heap собрал, вот оно и падает. Какой объект - неизвестно. Об этом можно лишь гадать, глядя на ваш код. Повторюсь - приведите строку падения. Не функцию, а строку. Тогда, возможно, кто-то сможет что-то предположить по этому поводу.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб В логах не написано на какой строке происходит ошибка.

Comment: Вот все что есть в логах в момент падения
https://pastebin.com/QJaVFv6q (Не влазило сюда, залил на пастебин)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Нашел строку, из за которой происходит падение. 
self.ids.task.add_widget(TaskLabel(id = str(self.i[0])))

Comment: Код объекта добавил сверху

Comment: Попробуйте передать `task` в Python файл через `ObjectProperty`, и в kv файле на уровне класса, в котором определен элемент `task` записать `task: task.__self__`. Если предоставите код этого класса - смогу написать подробнее.

Comment: @Lothric task - это BoxLayout класса Login. Добавил код c этим классом и kv файл, где используется task

Comment: @Lothric извините, перепутал, класса connected. Добавил kv файл connected тоже

Comment: Попробовал как вы сказали, не помогло